# How to change the Color of only one row in a table (HTML/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, row

I should make a table which the user will input its data.
So we have **Product Name** and **Price** and **Count** as our columns.

After this data is filled by the user the "**Sum**" column should be filled in **automatically** which is Price multiplied by Count.

I have completed the program `til here.
But I have problem with the continuation of the question:

I should change the **colour of the row** which has **highest sum** to **BLUE**
and change the **colour of the row** of the product which is the **most expensive** to **RED**.

How can it be done?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<style>
p{color:#F00};
</style>
<body>
<p> Please fill in the table and then click on "Submit Data": </p>
<table bordercolor="#333366" border="5">
<tr>
<td> <font style="background-color:#0F0"> Name of Product </td>
<td> <font style="background-color:#0F0"> Price </td>
<td> <font style="background-color:#0F0"> Count </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="text" id="textbox1"> </td>
<td> <input type="text" id="textbox2"> </td>
<td> <input type="text" id="textbox3"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="text" id="textbox4"> </td>
<td> <input type="text" id="textbox5"> </td>
<td> <input type="text" id="textbox6"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="text" id="textbox7"> </td>
<td> <input type="text" id="textbox8"> </td>
<td> <input type="text" id="textbox9"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Submit Data" id="Submit" onClick="Submit()">
</body>
<script>
function Submit()
{   


    var a=new Array(
    (document.getElementById("textbox1").value),
    (document.getElementById("textbox2").value),
    (document.getElementById("textbox3").value),
    (document.getElementById("textbox4").value),
    (document.getElementById("textbox5").value),
    (document.getElementById("textbox6").value),
    (document.getElementById("textbox7").value),
    (document.getElementById("textbox8").value),
    (document.getElementById("textbox9").value)
    );

    document.write("<table border='5' bordercolor='#333366'>");

    var c=0;
    document.write("<tr>");

    document.write("<td id='td1'>");
    document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML="Name of Product";
    document.write("</td>");

    document.write("<td id='td2'>");
    document.getElementById("td2").innerHTML="Price";
    document.write("</td>");

    document.write("<td id='td3'>");
    document.getElementById("td3").innerHTML="Count";
    document.write("</td>");

    document.write("<td id='td4'>");
    document.getElementById("td4").innerHTML="Sum";
    document.write("</td>");

    document.write("</tr>");

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        document.write("<tr>");
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            var sum=a[c-1] * a[c-2];

            if(j==3) {document.write("<td>" +sum+ "</td>");}

            else
            {
                document.write("<td>" +a[c]+ "</td>");
                c++;
            }
        }
        document.write("</tr>");
    }
    document.write("</table>");
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You better to start your code from scratch, without [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write)s ; ).

Comment: If your teacher recommended the `font` tag and/or `document.write` he is a fraud. Don't listen to him ever again about anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it: **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/EWIximi/1/edit)** I added some default values to demonstrate that it works. Just note that both results your looking for could end up being the same row, so I recommending styling both classes differently so that they can both appear on a single element, or changing the approach in general.

`<font>` is a deprecated tag and should never be used. You had an error in your html because your `font` tags were not closed: `</font>`.  If the intended use of an input is as a "number", I suggest `type="number"`. I don't see any need for id's on the inputs. Inline style should be avoided. It's best to write styles in CSS. Similarly, inline js should never be used other than for quick testing purposes. Read some of these results: **[Why is inline JS bad?](https://www.google.com/search?q=Why%20is%20inline%20js%20bad?)** Instead, use `addEventListener` in javascript to add the functionality you need. Lastly, `document.write()` should only be used for writing in fallback scripts for CDN scripts that fail to load. There's no need to write any html here. Just search the existing html and modify it (I recommend adding a class) as needed.

Markup:

```
<p> Please fill in the table and then click on "Submit Data": </p>

<table class="my-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><span>Name of Product</span> </td>
      <td><span>Price</span> </td>
      <td><span>Count</span> </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="number" value="50"></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="50"></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="50"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="number" value="10"></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="10"></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="number" value="10"></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="80"></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="10"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var subBtn = document.getElementById('submit');

subBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  highestSum();
  mostExpensive();
});

function mostExpensive() {
  var values = [];
  var cells = document.querySelectorAll('.my-table tbody td');
  for (var i=0; i<cells.length; ++i) {
    var cell = cells[i];
    var input = cell.querySelector('input');
    values.push(Number(input.value));
  }
  var max = Math.max.apply(Math, values);
  var key = values.indexOf(max);
  addClass(cells[key].parentNode, 'most-expensive');
}

function highestSum() {
  var rows = document.querySelectorAll('.my-table tbody tr');
  var sums = [];
  for (var i=0; i<rows.length; ++i) {
    var row = rows[i];
    sums.push(sumRow(row));
  }
  var max = Math.max.apply(Math, sums);
  var key = sums.indexOf(max);
  addClass(rows[key], 'highest-sum');
}

function sumRow(row) {
  var sum = 0;
  var inputs = row.querySelectorAll('input');
  for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; ++i) {
    sum+= Number(inputs[i].value);
  }
  return sum;
}

function addClass(elem, cls) {
  var current = elem.className;
  cls = (current) ? ' '+cls : cls;
  elem.className+= cls;
}
```

Comment: Thank you amazingly much. That helped me very much!! (My teacher hasn't taught me any of these useful codes...)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp) you can read about how to change the css of DOM elements using pure JavaScript.

You should add a class or id on the row you want to change the colour and then apply the colour:

```
document.getElementById("price-row").style.color="blue";
```